# Determine when subviews are added to tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, callback, subview

I have a `UITableView` with about 10 subviews. Some of the subviews are acting strangely in a few older iOS versions. I'd like to determine where the various subviews are being added to the tableView. **What's the best way to do this?**

Perhaps I can attach a callback to the tableView such that it's called whenever a subview is added?

Comment: do you have a table view with about 10 "cells" in it?  Do you have a class that is the table view datasource and delegate?

Comment: the tableView does contain a few cells. however it also has subviews that are not cells. I do have a class that adopts the tableViewDataSource and tableViewDelegate protocols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a good plan to me at least but a question is a question.

What you could do is observe the subviews property(NSArray) for changes, receive the callback and handle your case.

Again, if that's a good idea (looking at it form an architectural perspective) is a totally different question.

Edit: Sorry I think I misread, if you only want to figure out when what happens, ...guess you can do what I described above.... Or breakpoint into the drawing/layout methods. Either way.

Comment: indeed this would not be permanent code. just a hack to help figure something out